# Axios network error in expo react-native app

Tags: react-native, axios, expo, expo-go

Is there anyone know why an axios network error returns when an expo react-native app is being interacted with a physical iPhone using the expo go app?

Note: cors are enabled from the backend. No such error when interacting with the laptop browser

I tried after changing the url of http://127.0.0.1:8081/predict to my ip address. But did not work

```
useEffect(() => {
axios
  .post('http://127.0.0.1:8081/predict', {
    image: image,
  })
  .then((response) => {
    setData(response.data?.predicted_class);
    switch (response.data?.predicted_class) {
      case 0:
        setCircleText('Normal');
        setCircleOutlineColor('#36db1d');
        break;
      case 1:
        setCircleText('Mild');
        setCircleOutlineColor('#ffcc00');
        break;
      case 2:
        setCircleText('Moderate');
        setCircleOutlineColor('#ff851b');
        break;
      case 3:
        setCircleText('Severe');
        setCircleOutlineColor('#ff4136');
        break;
      case 4:
        setCircleText('Proliferative DR');
        setCircleOutlineColor('#741b47');
      default:
        setCircleText('Cannot read');
        setCircleOutlineColor('#c9c8c5');
    }
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error('Error:', error);
  });
```

}, []);

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You cannot send a request to `localhost` in react native if the app is running on your physical device because axios will call the device itself insetad of your pc/server.

You'll need to get your machine local IP (on windows just run `ipconfig` on cmd, mac/linux run `ifconfig` on terminal) and then, supposing your pc local ip is `192.168.1.123`, instead of requesting to `http://127.0.0.1:8081/predict` you'll need to call `http://192.168.1.123:8081/predict`.

Comment: tried that way too. but still getting the same error.

Comment: using postman in your pc, did you have any errors if you request to `http://192.168.1.123:8081/predict` too?

Comment: Yeah. I did not work with postman using that way

Comment: Can you provide on your answer the url with your pc ip thant you're sending the request?

Comment: @RasangaLakshith bummer that it didn't work for you. If it's any consolation, this solution helped me out.

Answer (score 0):

for react native expo android app, "{**YOUR_IP_ADDRESS**}:{PORT}"  change the ip address to "**10.0.2.2**" is worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I attempted all the suggested solutions, but unfortunately, none of them resolved my issue. Ultimately, I switched from Axios to Fetch, and that successfully solved the problem.